# Percentage-width children of a percentage width-parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a set of (pseudocode) elements, like so:

```
<div id="parent">
    <a><div id="child1 class="children"></a>
    ...
    <a><div id="child-n class="children"></a>
</div>
```

With styling like so:

```
.children{background:url(img/child-n.png)}
.parent{background:url(img/parent.png); width: 100%;}
```

What I need to accomplish is to have both the parent and children scale their width in relation to window width, with all of the children maintaining their position relative to their position within the parent.

Comment: ok. so work with precentage is good idea. what is the problem?

Comment: Here's a more simple way of asking: How do I make children elements scale in the same proportion as the parent? i.e.(parent is 70% of original size, children should also scale to 70% of that size)

Comment: just set their dimensions with `%`.
It'll be adjusted automatically when the window will resize, because the children div always be `70%` relative to their parent.
[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/6DsdJ/) to see my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html**

```
<div id="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
}
#parent {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 70%;    
    padding: 10px;
}
.child {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;    
    margin: 5px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DsdJ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is all wrong. Try correcting that first, and using percentage widths should work.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1" class="children"><a></a></div>
    <div id="child-n" class="children"><a></a></div>
</div>
```

Or put the divs inside of the a's, not sure which way you were going for.

Comment: It's pseudocode, which I noted, but I still should have closed those parentheses, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem :) width is computed based on its parent's width. So if you gave 100% width to the parent, and 70% width to the child, the child will always be 70% of the parent's width. Do you have a fiddle or something where this is running?

Comment: Dvir's fiddle is the solution I was looking for. It may not be the answer to my particular pickle I'm in, but it's a solution to the specific question I posed. Gratitude all around.